# Macro bringing data across to a new worksheet in a workbook based on critera

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I need assistance in writing a macro that will bring over 5 columns worth of data onto a new worksheet within the same workbook.
Background:  1st worksheet is a master list of all active employees, we want to use a macro that brings over employees onto a 2nd worksheet base on criteria = "specific text" in a column.

This tracking is done daily and the the macro should be able to remove employees already brought over from the previous day so we do not have duplicate data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample Excel Macro workbook with the macro which has comments written in it - you should be able to modify it to your needs.

[Download Macro Excel Workbook here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VyvWKDwfzckYhB7oHn0m421WM5Y4rl7y/view?usp=sharing)

Also pasting the code here...

```
Sub copyDataBasedOnCriteria()

Dim i As Integer
Dim columnToCheck As Integer
Dim outputRow As Integer

'-------------------------------------------
'Initialize these based on your requirement
'-------------------------------------------
numColumns = 5 'this is the number of columns in your data
numRows = 11 'this is the last row till where you have data, including header
columnToCheck = 4 'want to match the 4th column, D
filterValue = "Value 3" 'want to copy those employees where the data in field 'Attribute # 3' = 'Value 3'
'-------------------------------------------

Sheets("Destination").Activate
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents

For i = 1 To numColumns
    outputRow = 2
    Sheets("Destination").Range(whichCol(i) & "1").Value = Sheets("Source").Range(whichCol(i) & "1").Value
    For j = 2 To numRows
        If Sheets("Source").Range(whichCol(columnToCheck) & j).Value = filterValue Then
            Sheets("Destination").Range(whichCol(i) & outputRow).Value = Sheets("Source").Range(whichCol(i) & j).Value
            outputRow = outputRow + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

Sheets("Destination").Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

Function whichCol(colNumber As Integer) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNumber).Address(True, False), "$")
    whichCol = vArr(0)
End Function
```